# ReactPage showing blank screen while loading "AuthContextProvider" in react js while use with firebase auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

When im trying to add AuthContextProvider to mt react js beginner project its gives a blank screen error

It's showing a black screen while import
( {AuthContextProvider} from './context/AuthContext' ) in app.js file

its work fine if I comment the import {AuthContextProvider} line

right now I suck with this error can't figure out the error

[image]

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Login from "./Pages/Login";
import Signup from "./Pages/Signup";
import Account from "./Pages/Account";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import {AuthContextProvider} from './context/AuthContext'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/account" element={<Account />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth, db } from '../firebase';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {setDoc,doc} from 'firebase/firestore'

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function signUp(email, password) {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    setDoc(doc(db, 'users', email), {
        savedShows: []
    })
  }

  function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signUp, logIn, logOut, user }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function UserAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Comment: please check for console errors and share it here, whenever we get blank page, the errors are shown in console tab of inspect window in browser.

Comment: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

Comment: Please check your API key for firebase then.